# Django - Grabbing data from a sequence of forms and saving them at once

Tags: django, django-forms

Using django, I want to grab data from multiple forms before saving it to database, the purpose is to force user to enter all the data required.

How can I achieve this?

Note: Currently I'm using html tabs for my sequence of forms.

Thanks,
Majid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used achieved it by using form tag once and then placing my forms one by one like:

```
<form>
    {{ form_1 }}
    {{ formset }}
    {{ form_2 }}
    {{ form_3 }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</submit>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with Django FormSets

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/